# how to keep the design while using different languages

Tags: android

I'm making an app supporting one language only. It's a right to left language. The problem is that when I switch the language of my phone, the design of the app changes like `ImageView` or `TextView` go to the other side. I want to keep the design the same whatever the mobile language was.. is there any way to do this?

Comment: I guess you would need to *set the locale* for your activity / widgets / whatnot. If you search for that I presume you will find the answers you are looking for.

Comment: Would you please attach your code.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you, this really help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by setting local language at (OnCreate) here is the code:

```
val locale = Locale("ar")
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val config = Configuration()
    config.setLocale(locale)
    baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.resources.displayMetrics
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, when you define alignment or margins using alignStart or alignEnd or marginStart or marginEnd, I suggest you change it to "Left" and "Right". "Start" and "End" tags in the attributes define "flow", and flow changes when you change to a language like Arabic or Hebrew, whereas "Left" and "Right" tags define position and position won't change. I hope it helps.